# How do I debug a short code?

Tags: shortcode, debug

I am trying to debug a shortcode.  I have written the following function and placed in my theme's functions.php file:

```
function michael_function_shortcode() {
    return 'This is the return';
}
```

I have defined the shortcode as follows:

```
add_shortcode(‘michael’, ‘michael_function_shortcode’);
```

And I have included the shortcode on a page:

```
[michael]
```

I know the function is there because if I introduce errors I get messages because of debug=true, but `[michael]` just displays and is not replaced by 'This is the return" as expected.

Where do I go from here?  How do I debug this?

Comment: Is your actual code using quotes like `‘` and `’`, or just `'`?

Comment: Jacob - Thank you.  The single quotes in add_shortcode were not just ' as they should have been.  I corrected them and it works fine. I am just using return.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From [reading this guide](https://wpza.net/wordpress-setup/how-to-build-a-wordpress-shortcode/), could you try using a variable to output the return as such?

```
$output = 'This is the return';
return $output;
```

Also, if you're calling the shortcode with `do_shortcode('[michael]');` in a php file, you'll need to `echo` this, like so:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[michael]'); ?>
```

Comment: The problem was my quotes on the shortcode string.  All fixed.